# PowerShell command works with explicit path, fails when path comes from variable

Tags: powershell

I would really appreciate help if anyone out there has had this experience. I'm a bit new to PowerShell, but I think I'm right that this is weird behavior. I'm querying a remote computer's registry. I'm trying to write a script to do this for many computers. While testing, I found the syntax that returns the info I want. When I replaced an explicit registry path in the command with a variable containing the exact same path, I receive permission denied. Below is the text from the Powershell CLI, all three commands in the same window.

First command fails with $PackageRegPath holding the path string.

Second command displays and verifies the value of $PackageRegPath.

Third command succeeds with the value replacing $PackageRegPath.

Thanks in advance!

BigRogNJ

```
PS C:\windows\system32>  Invoke-Command -ComputerName $PC -ScriptBlock {Set-Location HKLM:\; Get-ChildItem $PackageRegPath | where {$_.Name -like "*InstallProperties*"} | Get-ItemProperty | select Displayname}
```

Requested registry access is not allowed.

```
+ CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SECURITY:String) [Get-ChildItem], SecurityException

+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Security.SecurityException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand

+ PSComputerName        : REDACTED



PS C:\windows\system32> $PackageRegPath

.\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\UserData\S-1-5-18\Products\F6CBFF0C20913AA419158961F6D28ABB\



PS C:\windows\system32>  Invoke-Command -ComputerName $PC -ScriptBlock {Set-Location HKLM:\; Get-ChildItem .\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\UserData\S-1-5-18\Products\F6CBFF0C20913AA419158961F6D28ABB\ | where {$_.Name -like "*InstallProperties*"} | Get-ItemProperty | select Displayname}
```

DisplayName                                          PSComputerName  RunspaceId

-----------                                          --------------  ----------

Microsoft System CLR Types for SQL Server 2014 (x64) REDACTED        89404d94-c1fd-4790-af88-d955a4c425b8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This comes up a lot.  You need to use the using: scope for local variables within invoke-command's scriptblock.

```bsh
$a = 'hi'
invoke-command computer { $using:a }
```